# Código so funciona no localhost

Tags: php, javascript, localhost, webcam

Este código PHP com JavaScript é para tirar fotos com a webcam. Mas só funciona no localhost. Quando está fora nao abre a webcam.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Tirar Fotos</title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<style>
        video { border: 1px solid #ccc; display: block; margin: 0 0 20px 0; }
        #canvas { margin-top: 20px; border: 1px solid #ccc; display: block; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div><video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video></div>
    <div><button id="snap">Tirar Foto</button></div>
    <div><button id="save">Salvar Foto</button></div>
    <div><canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480" style="position:relative; display:none"></canvas></div>
<script>

    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
        context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
        video = document.getElementById("video"),
        videoObj = { "video": true },
        errBack = function(error) {
                console.log("Video capture error: ", error.code); 
        };  
        if(navigator.getUserMedia) {
            navigator.getUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream) {
                video.src = stream;
                video.play();
            }, errBack);
        } else if(navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) {
            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
                video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
                video.play();
            }, errBack);
        }
        else if(navigator.mozGetUserMedia) {
            navigator.mozGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
                video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                video.play();
            }, errBack);
        }
    }, false);
    document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function() {      
        canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);       
        //alert(canvas.toDataURL());
    });
    document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", function() {      
        $.post('fotossalvar.php', {imagem:canvas.toDataURL()}, function(data){
        },'json');
    });
</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Como o nome sugere, este é o **pt.stackoverflow**. Todas as perguntas devem ser feitas em português (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Qual é a extensão do arquivo? É **.php**?

Answer (score 1):

Essa funcionalidade só funciona online em protocolo seguro HTTPS, de acordo com a mensagem abaixo:

> [Deprecation] getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins. To
>   use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a
>   secure origin, such as HTTPS. See https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins for more
>   details.

Se seu servidor online possui SSL, teste dentro dele que irá funcionar. Testei no Firefox e funcionou, porém, no Chrome, não.